# in a loop how to check if `mkdir` execute then stop loop?

Tags: php

below code I try to make for check how many folder in `dir` and create new one folder by ascending number, 
for exammple :
a. if `1` `2` in `dir` -> it will make a folder named `3`;
b. if `1` `5` in `dir`  -> I hope it can make a folder named `2`

but now in b. it will make -> `2` `3` .
so I'm wondering how to check if `mkdir` execute then stop loop in `for`?
Or any better idea?

```
// count folder
$folder = 0;
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./img/product/tmp/', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$it->setMaxDepth(0);
foreach($it as $fileinfo){
    if($fileinfo->isDir()){
        $folder++;
    }
}
// create folder
$new_dir = './img/product/tmp/';
for($i = 0; $i <= $folder; $i++){
    if(!is_dir($new_dir.$i)){// limit tmp_id  is the !exist
        mkdir($new_dir.$i);
        $tmp_id = $i;
        // check if mkdir then stop loop ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir` returns `true` on success, otherwise it returns `false`:

```
if (mkdir($new_dir.$1)) {
  // directory created, do your thing here
  break;
}
else {
  // failed to create directory
}
```

As far as I can tell, you only want to break out of your loop when you've successfully created a folder, so you probably don't need the `else` block at all in your situation

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it this way:

```
    mkdir $my_folder
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ;then
            echo "Error creating $my_folder
    else
            echo "Yey, $my_folder
            break;
    fi
```

Note, I don't see why you would WANT to break out of anything other than a while loop which could be satisfied as the way out of it.